# Terraform variable from gitlab CI/CD variables

Tags: terraform, gitlab-ci, hcl, terraform-provider-ibm

I understand that CI/CD variables can be used in HCL by counting on the fact that having them declared them with a TF_VAR_ prefix in the environment will enable me to look them up as input variables, then use them in the .tf file where I need them.

I did:

- set my variable via the UI in the GitLab project, as `TF_VAR_ibm_api_key`, then masked it.
- write a variable block for it in `main.tf`
- call it where I need it in the same file `main.tf`
- tried including the variable in `variables.tf`, same result
- read the documentation from gitlab and from terraform, but I'm not getting this right.

This is my `main.tf` file:

```
variable ibm_api_key {
}

terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13"
required_providers {
    ibm = {
    source = "IBM-Cloud/ibm"
    }
 }
}

provider "ibm" {
  ibmcloud_api_key = var.ibm_api_key
}
```

Expected behavior: the variable is passed from the CI/CD and added to the HCL code.

Current behavior: during ´plan´, the job falls with error code 1

```
$ terraform plan
var.ibm_api_key
  Enter a value: ╷
│ Error: No value for required variable
│ 
│   on main.tf line 1:
│    1: variable ibm_api_key {
│ 
│ The root module input variable "ibm_api_key" is not set, and has no default
│ value. Use a -var or -var-file command line argument to provide a value for
│ this variable.
╵
```

- although logically it can't seem to be the issue, I tried formatting the variable call as string interpolation, like:

  provider "ibm" {
  ibmcloud_api_key = "${var.ibm_api_key}"
  }
  naturally to no avail.
- although logically it can't seem to be the issue, I tried defining a type for the variable:

  variable ibm_api_key {
  type = string
  }
  naturally to no avail.
- In order to check if variables are passed from the CI/CD settings to the gitlab runner's environment, I added a variable that is neither protected nor masked, and assigned string  inserted a double check:

  - echo ${output_check}
  - echo ${TF_VAR_ibm_api_key}

which does not result in an error, but are not being printed either. Only the "echo" commands appear in the output.

```
$ echo ${output_check}
$ echo ${TF_VAR_ibm_api_key}
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:01
Job succeeded
```

Comment: So if you were to echo that variable before running `terraform plan`, would it display anything? Of course, don't post it here.

Comment: `variable "ibm_api_key" is not set` means that Terraform can't read `TF_VAR_ibm_api_key` environment variable. The problem is most likely inside Gitlab CI/CD configuration. Try to run simple bash script `echo ${TF_VAR_ibm_api_key}` and check if env is accessible. In other way you may try to add var type `variable ibm_api_key { type = string }`, but I not sure if that is causing the problem

Comment: I followed rzlvmp's suggestion and published its result. The problem was elsewhere but it was useful advice nonetheless -- I had already done it but didn't specify it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was in the CI/CD settings.
The variables were set to be exclusively passed to protected branches. I was pushing my code to an unprotected one, which prevented variables being passed. When merging the code to a protected branch, the variables showed up correctly. Variables are also correctly imported to Terraform, with the expected exclusion of the TF_VAR_ prefix.

TL;DR If you're having this issue in GitLab's CI/CD check your CICD variables' setting for protected branches, and if the branch you're pushing to corresponds to that setting.

Answer (score 5):

Providers typically have intrinsic environment variables configured in their schema and/or associated bindings for authentication. This situation is, according to the [provider authentication documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/IBM-Cloud/ibm/latest/docs#environment-variables), no different. You can authenticate the provider with an IBM API key from the GitlabCI project environment variables settings with:

```
IAAS_CLASSIC_API_KEY="iaas_classic_api_key"
```

Comment: Although the above is legit, it does not answer the problem stated in the question, which is also a viable way to set up a provider.

Comment: This does not constitute an answer in any way, and is not a workaround to a problem that was expressed. This is about the reason for a variable to be passed, not a request for help in achieving authentication.